# Generate a Tuple of a particular format

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I want to generate a Tuple of the below format.

```
Tuple = (2,20,200,2000)
```

Its basically adding  0's after a number. How do i generate these format tuple in python 3.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
seed = 2
tuple(seed * 10**n for n in range(4))
```

Given a seed it will create a list of `seed * 1`, `seed * 10`, `seed * 100`, etc. and then cast that as a tuple

Comment: no need to create an intermediate list, this is enough `tuple(seed * 10**n for n in range(4))`

Comment: @Netwave you're absolutely right have updated solution

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
tuple = ()
n = 5 # amount of items
num = 2 # number you want to have in the tuple
for x in range(n):
    new_item = num*10**x
    tuple += (new_item,)

print(tuple)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me

Answer (score 0):

You could use tail recursion (although tail recursion within python doesn't add much of a benefit):

```
tuple = (2, )
n = 4
def generate(n, tuple):
    if n == 1:
        return tuple
    else:
        tuple = tuple + (tuple[-1]*10, )
        return generate(n-1, tuple)

print(generate(n, tuple))
```

**Output:**

`>> (2, 20, 200, 2000)`